Retrieving values from all keys returns undefined with Firebase Realtime Database in JavaScript
In a small application I am making, I am trying to retrieve a specific note title and text from a parameter from a function I created. The parameter is a key.
function viewNote(note) {
    alert(note)
    var fetchedNote = database.ref('Users/' + localStorage.getItem('username') + "/Notes/" + note)
    fetchedNote.on('value', (snapshot2) => {
        var data = snapshot2.val()
        for (var key in data) {
            var value = data[key]
            var ti = value.title
            var te = value.text
            console.log(ti + ", " + te)
        }
    })
}

When I try to get all keys from parent key Notes, I get all child nodes without undefined errors. They work fine, but when I try to get a child node information title and text from Notes key, I get undefined. What can I do in such cases? Thank you for your time.
What I tried and What I want:
I tried by using the code above but still undefined error, I also used let before but still it doesn't work.
I want the title and text key values instead of undefined. Thanks.

Since you're getting a single node with a direct path to that node, the snapshot you get back contains only that node. So you don't need to loop over its children.
var fetchedNote = database.ref('Users/' + localStorage.getItem('username') + "/Notes/" + note)
fetchedNote.on('value', (snapshot2) => {
    var value = snapshot2.val()
    var ti = value.title
    var te = value.text
    console.log(ti + ", " + te)
})

